# Is it safe & possible to do almost everything on the cloud side with firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase for my new project. This will be used on both Android and IOS. As you can guess I don't want to write the same code over and over again for both OS.

I am considering to code most of the work with `Javascript` on the cloud functions. In order to do that I need to use `HTTP Requests` to call my functions since firebase doesn't support any other way to call cloud functions.

There is two question in my head about this.

1. Is this possible and does it makes sense?
2. Since I've been using `HTTP Requests` all the time isn't that make my app open to listening with tools like Wireshark etc if there are multiple users on the same network? (I know Firebase now supports `SSL` but do I have to but a domain and license for that?)

What is the best way to do it in an engineer's perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly move more of your app logic into Cloud Functions.  But it's not really true that the only way to invoke a Cloud Function is via HTTP.  You can also push data into your database to invoke a database trigger.  I gave a talk on this at Google I/O yesterday about how I made a game with all the logic in Cloud Functions.  [You can watch it here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g)

Comment: First of all, congrats! It was a great talk. It really makes sense when you consider the problems you may experience with HTTP Requests. I generally try to avoid sending everything to the server side in order to keep server less stressed. I think it might be a hassle for slow connections. But it doesn't seem like a problem for you at all. Can you explain further why?

Comment: Cloud Functions automatically scales up to meet demand, so you can't really "overstress" it, except when you have excessive write contention for some resources.  Anyway, there is always a tradeoff between the benefits of doing more work on the client vs more work on the backend.  I'm not too concerned about connection speed unless the payloads are rather large.  To make informed decision about performance, you can make use of Firebase Performance Monitoring, just released in beta at I/O.